# Eclipse ADT and Annotation Processing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I'm a new guy to eclipse and android stuff... I went to google and downloaded the latest dev pack for MAC OSX and imported the project... Alot of errors showed up... they were all related to "NameOfAClass_"... looking around i found out that the error is because AndroidAnnotations is not working... so i first read about it and digging a little further I got to Annotation Processing...

My current config seems right: Java compliance is 1.6. But the Option/Menu for Annotation Processing does not show up! I right click the project, go to compiler and i all i get is in the SS below... Can anyone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a problem with the ADT google provides. I downloaded LUNA and installed the SDK apart and now everything is working fine